# String manipulation in alternating order

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have a string

```
string value = "123456789";
```

now I need to re-arrange the string in the following way:

```
123456789
1       right 
12      left 
312     right 
3124    left 
53124   right 
...
975312468 result
```

Is there a fancy linq one liner solution to solve this?

My current (working but not so good looking) solution:

```
string items = "abcdefgij";
string result = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 != 0)
    {
        result = result + items[i];
    }
    else
    {
        result = items[i] + result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Such tasks usually can be solved by devising a math formula that generates the indices to pick from. E.g. `[0...length/2]*2+1 || [0...length/2]*2` in pseudo syntax

Comment: LINQ and indices don't work well together, a loop is often more readable. But you could use a stringbuilder

Comment: @TimSchmelter `string.Join(indices.Select(i => str[i]))` would be nice I think.

Comment: @TimSchmelter you can zip it with range, if you do need index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use length of the `res` as variable to decide from which side to append

```
items.Aggregate(string.Empty, (res, c) => res.Length % 2 == 0 ? c + res : res + c);
```

Alternative solution would be zipping with range

```
items.Zip(Enumerable.Range(0, items.Length), (c, i) => new {C = c, I = i})
    .Aggregate(string.Empty, (res, x) => x.I % 2 == 0 ? x.C + res : res + x.C)
```

**EDIT:** don't really needed `ToCharArray`...

Comment: wow I like the idea to use the result string's length as direction indicator, +1!

Comment: If you want to squeeze more performance from this one-liner, operate with `Char`s and then convert them into string at the end.

Comment: @klappvisor - something like `new string((items.Aggregate(new List<char>(items.Length), (res, c) => { if (res.Count % 2 != 0) { res.Add(c); } else { res.Insert(0, c); } return res; })).ToArray())`? Slightly more performant, but much more readable. ;)

Comment: @Corak yes, Not sure about `List` since every time, when you insert at the beginning it will shift entire list... but I got your point, usually when you need performance, code clarity suffers...

Comment: Tested it with a `string` of length 284541. With string concatenations it's about 23 seconds, with the list it's about 3 seconds. Out of curiosity, how would one avoid `Insert`/shifting in this scenario? Direct index access, maybe?

Comment: @Corak choose data structure with cheap insertion in front and at the end or event use solution based on zip and insert in exact place

Comment: Okay, this is what I came up with: `public static T[] LeftRight<T>(T[] values) { var result = new T[values.Length]; var rI = values.Length % 2 == 0 ? ((values.Length / 2) - 1) : (values.Length / 2); for (var vI = 0; vI < values.Length; vI++) { if (vI % 2 != 0) { result[rI + ((vI / 2) + 1)] = values[vI]; } else { result[rI - (vI / 2)] = values[vI]; } } return result; }` -- same string length as above now in apparently `0.00072` seconds.

Answer (score 8):

```
string value = "123456789";
bool b = true;
string result = value.Aggregate(string.Empty, (s, c) =>
{
    b = !b;
    return b ? (s + c) : (c + s);
});
```

I actually don't like local variables inside LINQ statements, but in this case `b` helps alternating the direction. (@klappvisor showed how to live without `b`).

Comment: I think `b` should start life as `true`?

Comment: even though I do like how you arrive at the same result I think the code in the question is more readable.

Comment: @Meehow In my years of experience with my co-workers I came to the conclusion that even readability can be very subjective :)

Answer (score 3):

Resulting string is chars in evens positions concatenated to chars in odds positions in reverse order:

```
string value = "123456789";

var evens = value.Where((c, i) => i % 2 == 1);
var odds = value.Where((c, i) => i % 2 == 0).Reverse();

var chars = odds.Concat(evens).ToArray();
var result = new string(chars);
```

Comment: Not very optimal in terms of performance... example why many people think Linq is slow...

Comment: This does iterate through the input sequence twice (maybe three times, depending on how Reverse() is implemented). However, it avoids repeated string concatenations, which can reallocate memory over and over again. I wouldn't be so sure that it's slower than the "one-liner" that constantly reallocates the string result.

Comment: @MattDillard yes, in accepted answer it uses string concatenation  for the sake of clarity, but if you want performance you can operate with chars and then join them into string at the end and still be one liner